# Anonymous function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: $.fblogin is not a function" when I call

```
$.fblogin({
          fbId: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
          permissions: 'email,user_birthday',
          success: function (data) {
            console.log('User birthday' + data.birthday + 'and email ' + data.email);
        }
      });
```

The function is defined bellow:

```
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        // CommonJS
        factory(require('jquery'));
    } else {
        // Browser globals
        factory(jQuery);
    }
}(function ($) {
    $.extend({
        /**
         * fblogin
         * @property {object}  options      - settings for fblogin plugin.
         * 
         * Required:
         * options.fbId         {string}    - the Facebook app id
         *
         * Optional:
         * options.permissions  {string}    - a comma seperated list of FB permissions. See http://bit.ly/1plqJSs
         * options.fields       {string}    - a comma seperated list of field ids. See http://bit.ly/1plrevO 
         * options.success      {function}  - callback that will be triggered when data is successfully returned from FB.
         * options.error        {function}  - callback that will be triggered by any errors.
         */
        fblogin: function (options) {

            /**
             * Private Props
             * @property {object}  __               - add private module functions here.
             * @property {object}  isSdkLoaded      - a flag for when the FB SDK has loaded.
             * @property {object}  isFbInitiated    - a flag for when FB.init has been called.
             * @property {object}  $dfd             - stores an instance of jquery Deferred.
             */
            var __,           
                isSdkLoaded,      
                isFbInitiated,
                $dfd;

            options = options || {};
            isSdkLoaded = false;
            isFbInitiated = false;
            $dfd = $.Deferred();

            // PRIVATE FUNCTIONS
            __ = {  
                init: function () {
                    // FB ID is required
                    if (!options.fbId) {
                            throw new Error('Required option "fbId" is missing!');
                    }

                    options.permissions = options.permissions || '';
                    options.fields = options.fields || '';
                    options.success = options.success || function(){};
                    options.error = options.error || function(){};

                    __.listenForFbAsync();
                },
                listenForFbAsync: function () {
                    if (window.fbAsyncInit) {
                        var notMyFunction = window.fbAsyncInit;
                    }
                    // listen for FB SDK load
                    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                        __.initFB();
                        isSdkLoaded = true;
                        if (notMyFunction) { notMyFunction(); }
                    };

                    if (isSdkLoaded || window.FB) {
                        window.fbAsyncInit();
                        return;
                    }
                },
                initFB: function () {
                    if (!isFbInitiated) {
                        window.FB.init({
                            appId      : options.fbId,
                            cookie     : true,
                            xfbml      : true,
                            version    : 'v2.0'
                        });

                        isFbInitiated = true;
                    }

                    $dfd.notify({status: 'init.fblogin'});
                },
                loginToFB: function () {
                    window.FB.login(function(response) {
                        if (response.authResponse) {

                            $dfd.notify({
                                status: 'authenticate.fblogin',
                                data: response
                            });

                        } else {
                            // mimic facebook sdk error format
                            $dfd.reject({
                                error: {
                                    message: 'User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.'
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }, {
                        scope: options.permissions, 
                        return_scopes: true
                    });
                },
                getFbFields: function (accessToken) {
                    FB.api('/me', {fields: options.fields}, function(response) {
                        if (response && !response.error) {
                            $dfd.resolve(response);
                        } 
                        else {
                            $dfd.reject(response);
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

            // This monitors the FB login progresssion
            // 1. Init FB
            // 2. FB.login
            // 3. Get user data
            $dfd.progress(function (response) {
                if( response.status === 'init.fblogin' ) {
                    __.loginToFB();
                } else if( response.status === 'authenticate.fblogin' ) {
                     __.getFbFields(response.data.authResponse.accessToken);
                } else {
                    dfd.reject();
                }
            });

            // point callbacks at deffereds
            $dfd.done(options.success);
            $dfd.fail(options.error);

            // here we go!
            __.init();

            return $dfd;
        }
    });
}));
```

Comment: Check in console, is jquery getting loaded again after this script?

Comment: Thanks @nikhil.agw this was actually the problem. I put the script down in the page and it worked! If you want you can reply to this question and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Great it worked for you :) Ok replying to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your jQuery is getting loaded again after the above script. You can check in console or move the script down in the page and verify.